# Why did the cop make this decision?

Tags: plot-explanation, polisse

At the end of the French movie [*Polisse*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1661420/) a cop kills herself when she gets promoted and she notices her coworkers don't "care" but I'm sure there were many pre-factors I missed during the film. But what were they?

I felt that maybe she never dealt with her own childhood abuse and the young boy near the end reminded her of her pain. Is that likely the only reason or was there more I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

She killed herself because she couldn't handle her boulimia anymore, she was single (her fiancé left her because of her boulimia, and because he couldn't support her anymore), she couldn't have babies, and at the end, she didn't have friends anymore. That's why she commited suicide! I don't think that she had been abused, she acted weirdly when the little guy talked about his teacher because she doubted : is it possible for a child to really love an adult? Does she really has to punish the man? Is he really a bad guy?

Comment: *"(Sorry for my bad english, I'm French :) )*" - Your English is pretty good, actually.